# Jquery datatable buttons make inner div size of button

Tags: html, css, datatables

Hi I'm trying to use tooltipster to get tooltips on the buttons from jquery datatable but the div is only the size of the content and i can't seem to get it to be the size of the button

I checked the css on tools and it won't get it's parent width cause there is a span

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary buttons-pdf buttons-html5 btn-default" tabindex="0" aria-controls="tblConsumos" type="button">
    <span>
          <div class="tips tooltipstered">
              <svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-file-pdf fa-w-12" style="color: red;" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="far" data-icon="file-pdf" role="img">
              </svg><i class="far fa-file-pdf" style="color:red;">
          </div>
    </span>
</button>
```

I know this might be possible with javascript but I was looking for a css approach but i have no idea how to bypass that span.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
.buttons-pdf{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}


.buttons-pdf .tooltipstered {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.buttons-pdf .tooltipstered::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.buttons-pdf:hover .tooltipstered {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: this does not work, just hides the icon on the button